# Quicker Queries - Drupal 7 View to db_query

Tags: mysql, drupal

I have a view showing users profiles (from profile 2 module). Each user has up to 3 different profiles. I want to produce a view that shows all user profiles and one row per user with all their profile fields combined in one row. I have gotten this to work in views... YAY. However, when I try to use it on the live site with 900+ users (3 profiles each) it fails to execute (white screen). If I limit it to 100 results it works. So I was thinking maybe I could hard code a db_query to make it quicker. Two part question:

First I tried to paste the query into phpmyadmin with a few modifications [(See it here)](http://hastebin.com/raw/nuyalidumo)

What happens almost works... the profile UID and Profile Types show up right. However the other fields all have "profile2" as data. I know this is an error with my query but I am unsure how to modify the 'profile2' part of the query to produce the data i want.

Second question.... any ideas on how to make this more efficient since I wont be using views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use continue to use views but add pagination so you only see 100 results at a time.

If you want to see all the data in one go then you could export it using the [Views Data Export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module.